# Run RapSearch-Program with Torque PBS and qsub

Tags: sequence, qsub, torque, blast

My problem is that I have a cluster-server with Torque PBS and want to use it to run a sequence-comparison with the program rapsearch.
The normal RapSearch command is:

```
./rapsearch -q protein.fasta -d database -o output -e 0.001 -v 10 -x t -z 32
```

Now I want to run it with 2 nodes on the cluster-server.
I've tried with: `echo "./rapsearch -q protein.fasta -d database -o output -e 0.001 -v 10 -x t -z 32" | qsub -l nodes=2` but nothing happened.

Do you have any suggestions? Where I'm wrong? Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard output (and error output) files are placed in your home directory by default; take a look. You are looking for a file named `STDIN.e[numbers]`, it will contain the error message.

However, I see that you're using `./rapsearch` but are not really being explicit about what directory you're in. Your problem is therefore probably a matter of changing directory into the directory that you submitted from. When your terminal is in the directory of the rapsearch executable, try `echo "cd \$PBS_O_WORKDIR && ./rapsearch [arguments]" | qsub [arguments]` to submit your job to the cluster.

Other tips:

1. You could add rapsearch to your path if you use it often. Then you can use it like a regular command anywhere. It's a matter of adding the line `export PATH=/full/path/to/rapsearch/bin:$PATH` to your `.bashrc` file.
2. Create a submission script for use with qsub. [Here](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/HPC/Sample_Qsub_script.html) is a good example.

Comment: Thank you! I've added the program-path to .bashrc. Additionally I copied all needed files to the home directory. This worked fine.  Thanks a lot jonaslb.